# Chain rule for partial derivatives from properties of differential

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having some head scratching with the chain rule applied to partial derivatives.

I know that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions then $d(f \circ g(x)) = df(g(x))dg(x)$. This is quite clear. I know also that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(x) = ⟨\nabla f(x), e_i⟩$ if $e_i$ is the $i$-th base vector.

However, I don't really understand how these two things combine to achieve the partial derivative of composite functions. Suppose for example I have to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(g(x, y), h(x,y))$. I don't really understand how to do this.

Comment: I am using detestable but convenient physics notation:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f\Big(g(x,y),h(x,y)\Big)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \color{red}g}f\Big(g(x,y),h(x,y)\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y)+
\frac{\partial}{\partial \color{red}h}f\Big(g(x,y),h(x,y)\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}h(x,y)\,.
$$

Comment: @KurtG. I've seen this formula but I can't really see where that comes from.

Comment: It is the chain rule for a compositon of a  function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ with a function $(g,h):\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2\,.$ We see this a lot when $g$ and $h$ depend only on a single variable $t\,.$ Then the formula is the scalar product of the gradient of $f$ with the tangent vector to a curve in $\mathbb R^2\,.$ The fact that we partially differentiate this all w.r.t. to $x$ does not change that rule.

Comment: @KurtG Do *not* write such garbage. It is just as easy to teach people correct and meaningful notation.

Comment: @TedShifrin with my mathematician's hat on I agree.

Comment: @Folpo13 Do you see Ted's issues with that physicist's notation? It suggests that we differentiate w.r.t to functions $g,h.$ But we differenitiate $f$ w.r.t its two variables. How would you fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the chain rule you have written if you extend it to use matrix multiplication. Define $G:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $G:(x,y)\mapsto (g(x,y), h(x,y))$. Then the composition we care about is $H(x,y) = f(G(x,y))$. The chain rule says

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(g(x,y),h(x,y)) &= \left(df\rvert_{(x,y) = G(x,y)}\right)\left(dG\rvert_{(x,y)}\right)e_1 \\
&= (f_x(g(x,y),h(x,y)), f_y(g(x,y),h(x,y)) \begin{pmatrix}g_x & g_y \\ h_x & h_y\end{pmatrix}e_1 \\
&= (f_x(g(x,y),h(x,y)), f_y(g(x,y),h(x,y)) \begin{pmatrix}g_x \\h_x \end{pmatrix} \\
&= f_x(g(x,y),h(x,y)) g_x(x,y) + f_y(g(x,y),h(x,y))h_x(x,y).
\end{aligned}
$$

Ther only tricky parts here is the definition of the derivative of a function from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and the fact that we have used the fact that $\nabla f := (df)^T$ to rewrite your definition of a partial as a matrix multiplication since $\langle \nabla f, e_1\rangle = (\nabla f)^Te1 = (df)e_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f = (f_1, \ldots, f_q)$ is a function with values in $\mathbf{R}^q$ and defined over an open set of $\mathbf{R}^p;$ likewise, let $g = (g_1, \ldots, g_r)$ defined on an open set containing the image set of $f$ and with values on $\mathbf{R}^r.$ Then $Df(x)$ is of dimensions $(q,p)$ and $Dg(y)$ is of dimensions $(r,q);$ in addition, the rows of $Df(x)$ or $Dg(y)$ are the derivatives of $f_j$ and $g_i,$ respectivel, and the columns of are the partial derivatives. This is so because the partial derivative is the derivative of $t \mapsto f(x + te_k)$ and the chain rule demonstrates this derivative at $t = 0$ is $Df(x) e_k$ which is the $k$th column. Whereas the function $f_k$ is obtained by dot product $x \mapsto e_k \cdot f(x) = e_k^\intercal f(x)$ (if $f(x)$ is writen as a $q$-column vector) whose derivative is $e_k^\intercal Df(x)$ (chain rule again). Therefore, the $k$ partial derivative of $g \circ f$ at $x$ (with $y = f(x)$) is $D(g \circ f)(x) e_k = Dg(y) (Df(x) e_k)$ and if we want to extrat the $h$th coordinate, then we premultiply by $e_h^\intercal$, so $D_k(g_h \circ f)(x) = e_h^\intercal Dg(y) Df(x) e_k.$