# What differentiation rule is used in this passage?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm studying the dependence of solutions of Cauchy problem to starting conditions

I have the flux function $\Phi : I \times B \rightarrow \Omega$ which maps $(x, \xi, \eta)$ to $y_{\xi \eta}(x)$ where $y_{\xi \eta}$ is the solution of the Cauchy problem
$\begin{cases} y' = f(x, y) \\
y(\xi) = \eta \end{cases} $

In a proof my books states $\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} f(x, y_{\xi \eta}(x)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y_{\xi \eta}(x)) \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}y_{\xi \eta}(x)$

What is going on? Is this some application of the chain rule?

Comment: Yes, chain rule.

Comment: @Raskolnikov I understand, but I can't see how it's used in this case. Maybe I'm drowning in an inch of water

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the problem. Chain rule is chain rule. There's nothing much to say about it. Is it the fact that $f$ has a two variable dependency that is confusing you? That is irrelevant since only the $y$ part depends on $\xi$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov maybe I'm misunderstanding something but isn't the $y$ on the first $\partial y$ "denominator" supposed to be $y_{\xi \eta}$? Where does $y$ even come from? Also I'm not really sure what does it mean to differentiate with respect a function

Comment: It's just a matter of notation. You could write it like you say, but it would just clutter notation for one. The second reason they don't, is that the notation really means derivative function of the function $f: (x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ w.r.t. to $y$ and that derivative function is then evaluated at the point $(x,y_{\xi \eta}(x))$.

Comment: "Isn't $\partial y$ supposed to be $\partial y_{\xi\eta}\,$?" That's what I meant with detestable notation in my comment to your other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864138/chain-rule-for-partial-derivatives-from-properties-of-differential). Some like it some don't. What matters is that *you* know what you are doing.

Comment: @KurtG. I see. This had just confused me a lot, I was going crazy for really nothing. Thank you all for your explanation.